# How can I change settings within Control Panel with Bat files?

Tags: file, batch-file, controls, panel

I am trying to make my job a little bit more time efficient by using a batch file to change multiple settings within control panel all at once. I can do this manually but if you are setting up 20+ computers it can get a little time consuming. I do not work much with batch files so I do not have any idea where I should start or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is actually interact with Windows registry from .bat. 
Exactly, which configurations do you wanna change?

Comment: To clarify this - control panel changes generally alter the registry and by duplicating those registry changes, with reg.exe, you can set up many machines with a single batch file, in seconds.

Comment: I want to be able to change Action Control Center settings along with Firewall settings and if it is possible uninstall some items.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy, you can easily find info online about how to do that, MS should have some tutorials on MSDN too. Also, you can done almost all those things thru PowerSheel scripts instead of bat (which I personally think is the best approach)

Anyways, to change ACC you need to go over registry key

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Action Center
```

Firewall settings at

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\
```

Installed software and its uninstall commands at

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

be careful, registry changes can harm the system.